# Evaluating a 'WolframAlphan' integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals, wolfram-alpha

This problem has to be the real and integral part of Christmas... :)

Here goes:

> What is the minimum value of $k$ such that
>   $$\Re\left\{\int_{e^{\large 1/\pi}}^{\pi^{\large 1/e}}\left[%
> \left(\frac{x^e}{\pi^{x}}\right)^{ex/\pi} -
> \left(\frac{e^{x}}{x^{\pi}}\right)^{\pi x/e}\right]^{k}\,\mathrm{d}x\right\}
> =
> 1?
> $$

edit: @DonnyFrank has provided a visualization showing that $k$ can take infinitely many values

**My Observations**

> The integral is negative for odd integers of $k$ and positive for even integers of $k$.

> The integral is complex for non-integer $k$ (it is already complex for any value of $k$ ;)

> The real part of the integral is very close to $1$ as $k$ approaches $10$ - in fact it surpasses $10$ at around $k=9.897$.

**My Attempt**

No clue. I know that $k$ is not an integer so the binomial theorem wouldn't help at all.

> Merry Christmas and a Happy New Year!

Comment: Any motivation for this?

Comment: @MartínVacasVignolo I was playing around with functions and integrals in Wolfram, so...

Comment: Keep playing, then, and have lots of fun! :D

Comment: why man.... just, why this amazingly ugly integral with weird swapping of bases and exponents... LOL

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a plot of your function:

[image]

As you can see there are infinite values of `k` such that `f(k)=1`, the first of  which is `~9.89577716596896`.

Code used to generate this plot:

```
from mpmath import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def f(k):
    return re(quad(lambda x: ((x**e / pi**x)**(e*x/pi) - (e**x / x**pi)**(pi*x/e))**k, [e**(1/pi), pi**(1/e)]))

kl = np.linspace(0,20,1000)
yl = [f(k) for k in kl]

plt.plot(kl, yl, label='f(k)')
plt.plot((0, 20), (1, 1), label='f(k)=1')
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel('k')
plt.ylabel('f(k)')

plt.show()
```

Finding the first value such that `f(k)=1`:

```
print(findroot(lambda k: f(k) - 1, 9.0))
```

I doubt any "nice" representation can be found for this value, unless you have a particular reason one should exist.